# Looking for a book on a 1st differential equations course

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, book-recommendation

I'm currently taking differential equations but the guide book (Elementary differential equations and boundary value problems) is aimed for engineers (much like the calculus one from Stewart). I'm looking for a book with the classic mathematical format (definition, theorem, corollary...) and not too much talk or applications.

Thanks

Comment: @nmasanta Not really, I was asking for a specific type of book in the sense that I wanted the mathematical format of Definition, theorem etc. Like Friedberg does on Linear algebra.

Comment: Have you try any book recommended there ? @Manuel Pico ~

Comment: They are aimed for Physics mostly so not really what Im looking for @nmasanta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm certainly no expert, but I have particularly enjoyed An Introduction to Ordinary  Differential Equations by Earl Coddington. I used it along side Elementary Differential Equations and Boundary Value Problems by Boyce and Diprima and it is definitely a nice complement to that.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

The books

- [Differential Equations : Theory, Technique, and Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0072863153) by G.F simmons and Steven Krantz
- [An introduction to Ordinary Differential Equations](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486659429) by E.A. Coddington

fulfills your requirements!